# React, NodeJS, MySQL setValue of date in date input

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, typescript

I need to setValue of a date input that I retrieve from the DB(MySQL).
My Model has two date pickers (checkIn and CheckOut) as **string** on React and Node, at mySQL it is set to date type.

This is my useEffect:

```
const { register, handleSubmit, formState, setValue } = useForm<VacationModel>();
const navigate = useNavigate();
const params = useParams();

useEffect(() => {
    const id = +params.vacationId; // Same name as router parameter.
    vacationsService.getOneVacation(id)
        .then(vacation => {
            setValue("vacationId", vacation.vacationId);
            setValue("destination", vacation.destination);
            setValue("description", vacation.description);
            setValue("checkIn", vacation.checkIn);
            setValue("checkOut", vacation.checkOut);
            setValue("price", vacation.price);
            setValue("image", vacation.image);
        })
        .catch(err => notifyService.error(err));
}, []);
```

How is it possible to set the correct dates from the DB in my Edit component?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer.
At the database I formatted the date from %d/%m/%Y to %Y-%m-%d.
After that I had to make the string go to this specific format by using:

```
setValue("checkIn", new Date(vacation.checkIn).toISOstring().split('T');
setValue("checkOut", new Date(vacation.checkOut).toISOstring().split('T');
```

And then the values were inserted correctly.
Hope it will help others.